# CTE goes recursive and fails

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have created a very small CTE recursive function but seems it goes recursive all the time and fails.
Please find details inline:

Table Name & Data:

```
insert into dbo.HierarchyEmployee     
Values
(1,1, 'Name1'),
(2,1, 'Name2'),
(3,4, 'Name3'),
(4,5, 'Name4'),
(5,2, 'Name5'),
(6,4, 'Name6'),
(7,1, 'Name7'),
(8,8, 'Name8'),
(9,3, 'Name9'),
(10,1, 'Name10')
```

Ideal Result Set:

```
HierarchyParent HierarchyID Name
1   1   Name
1   2   Name2
1   7   Name7
1   10  Name10
```

I tried to achieve this through reclusive CTE as I wanted to look how recursion works.

Below is the query used:

```
WITH CTE_HierarchyEmployee
AS
(
    SELECT  H.HierarchyID,
            H.HierarchyParent,
            H.Name
            FROM dbo.HierarchyEmployee H
            WHERE H.HierarchyID = 1
            UNION ALL
    SELECT  H.HierarchyID,
            H.HierarchyParent,
            H.Name
            FROM
            dbo.HierarchyEmployee H
            INNER JOIN  CTE_HierarchyEmployee CTEH
            ON H.HierarchyParent = cteh.HierarchyID
)
SELECT * FROM CTE_HierarchyEmployee
```

Error:

> Msg 530, Level 16, State 1, Line 41
>
> The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.

Appreciate you input on how to resolve the revulsion.

Comment: Your sample output is produced with SELECT FROM dbo.HierarchyEmployee WHERE HIERARCHYID = 1, no recursion necessary. Are you trying to traverse a tree?

Comment: Your first row of data is I'd 1, parent id 1. Your CTE will recur indefinitely on that record. Can add a condition to join to not join to self or set parent id to null.

Comment: Hi Shannon - Agree that ROOT should not have any parent (Like OWNER is OWNER and nobody above that). Setting NULL in Parent Hierarchy would fix the problem however consider the business scenario when ultimate parent is identified based on a match if hierarchy id equals to Parent ID. Nevertheless can you please explain why keeping parent id NOT NULL makes CTE reclusive? (Perhaps I am not able to visualise the processing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** I figure out the reason. Problem is in the sample data. The parent most HierarchyID = 1 is also having the ParentId = 1. In "NORMAL" situation this can't be the case, most of the times parentID of top most id is NULL. Since parent and HierarchyID are same (1) it is going into the loop of 1 is parent of 1. 
2 ways you can solve the problem: 
1. Update parentID of HierarchyID = 1 to NULL 
2. Add extra where condition in Recursive query where H.HierarchyID <> 1

You just need to add OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)  at the end of the query to over come the limitation of 100 recursion. See:

```
WITH CTE_HierarchyEmployee
AS
(
    SELECT  H.HierarchyID,
            H.HierarchyParent,
            H.Name
            FROM dbo.HierarchyEmployee H
            WHERE H.HierarchyID = 1
            UNION ALL
    SELECT  H.HierarchyID,
            H.HierarchyParent,
            H.Name
            FROM
            dbo.HierarchyEmployee H
            INNER JOIN  CTE_HierarchyEmployee CTEH
            ON H.HierarchyParent = cteh.HierarchyID
)
SELECT * FROM CTE_HierarchyEmployee
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: Hi Mangal - MAXRECURSION would only avoid failure but problem of recursion will remains there (See the SSMS SQL Tab for 'Executing..) post you run the code. I wanted to understand the reason of recursion in the code. Can you help?

Comment: Hi Mikurshi - You are right that simple query would achieve the same but I wanted to test CTE revulsion.

Comment: Hi @AkashChandra,
I figure out the reason.  Problem is in the sample data.  The parent most HierarchyID = 1 is also having the ParentId = 1.  In "NORMAL" situation this can't be the case, most of the times parentID of top most id is NULL.  Since parent and HierarchyID are same (1) it is going into the loop of 1 is parent of 1. 
2 ways you can solve the problem:
1. Update parentID of HierarchyID = 1 to NULL
2. Add extra where condition in Recursive query 
where H.HierarchyID <> 1

Comment: Hi @Mangal  - This makes sense about infinite looping. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Mangal, could you edit your answer to reflect the actual solution as you've noted in these comments? I. E. that it's because of how the data is?